# How to get position of <img> tag in ontouchListner of webview

Tags: android, webview, touch, image

I have created a custom webview having scroll listner and touch Listner. I am loading the an HTML code in it, for which I have used javascript which creates `img` tags using **for** Loop.

```
String htnlString = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body style = \"text-align:center\"><script type=\"text/javascript\">for(a=1;a<=10;a++)document.write('<img style=\"border-style:dotted;border-width:10px;border-color:black;\"src=\"http://shiaislamicbooks.com/books_snaps/EN183/'+a+'.jpg\" alt=\"Page Not Found\"/>');</script></body></html>";

wv.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htnlString, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Now I want to get the position of `img` tag onTouchListner of webview.
Is there any method in webview which returns me the postion of `<img>` tag.

**Whole code**

```
import android.content.Context;
   import android.util.AttributeSet;
   import android.util.Log;
   import android.view.MotionEvent;
   import android.webkit.WebView;

   public class scorllableWebview extends WebView {
    private OnScrollChangedCallback mOnScrollChangedCallback;

public scorllableWebview(final Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public scorllableWebview(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public scorllableWebview(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs,
        final int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onScrollChanged(final int l, final int t, final int oldl,
        final int oldt) {
    super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
    if (mOnScrollChangedCallback != null)
        mOnScrollChangedCallback.onScroll(l, t);
}

public OnScrollChangedCallback getOnScrollChangedCallback() {
    return mOnScrollChangedCallback;
}

public void setOnScrollChangedCallback(
        final OnScrollChangedCallback onScrollChangedCallback) {
    mOnScrollChangedCallback = onScrollChangedCallback;
}

/**
 * Impliment in the activity/fragment/view that you want to listen to the
 * webview
 */
public static interface OnScrollChangedCallback {
    public void onScroll(int l, int t);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    Log.d("onTouchEvent", event.getAction() + "");

    // I want to get the position of <img> tag here.
   // what is the method which return the <img> tag position

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
 }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this depends on what you mean by getting the coordinates of the touching.

if you mean in android coordinates , here's a possible solution :

- for the onTouchListener of the webview , store the coordinate and return false , so that it would be handled normally on the websiew's content.
- in the javascript of touching the img tag in the webview , call a function of android using the method [addJavascriptInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29) (more info [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2008/09/using-webviews.html) ) , telling it that the img tag was touched.
- in this function , you can take the coordinates that were saved before.

in case you mean html coordinates , you can skip the first step , and simply pass them to the android framework.

Comment: i've already put the links. Since i'm not an expert in javascript , i might make mistakes. Plus you still didn't write what is your definition of coordinates - is it compared to the screen , is it from the webview , etc...